# How do i read this type associative data in R?

Tags: r, dataset, nodes, associative

i have a dataset like following:

col1  | col2

```
A,B | C
F,A | U
```

two columns are given and in one column, 2 points A and B given against one point C which is in the second column, so when i try to read this in R using this

```
datafile  <- read.table("C:\\Users\\z\\Desktop\\Data\\data.txt",  header=T, fill
= TRUE ,sep="\t")


x_edgelist <- datafile
```

And counting no of nodes using this command

```
length(levels(x_edgelist$col1))
length(levels(x_edgelist$col2))
```

it gives wrong number of nodes of Col1 and Col2. How to read this type of data in R.. is this data is in any other format  ? how to read this type of associative data  ?

Comment: Please giva a reproducible example. Without the file data.txt, nobody can confirm the problem or check the parameters to `read.table` or really find the problem.

Comment: Maybe: `length(unique(unlist(sapply(as.character(df1$col1), strsplit, split = ","))))`

Comment: @bernhard i am asking for correct format to read this type of associative data

Comment: I still don't understand the question. If you want to know how to use the `read.table`function for your data, you will need to specify the input format (e.g. is the seperator `\t` or `|`?). Again, preferably in form of a reproducible example. If the question is about how to preferably store the data within R, than that depends heavily on how you want to access/use the data afterwards. What does "A,B | C" mean?Do you want to find C when searching for A or is A,B an edge and you want to Count all edges that involve A. Is A,B the same as B,A or not? Please explain further.

Comment: @Bernhard i am plotting a bi-partite graph in R  in which A,B nodes connect to node C... but as i mention the code i used to read this data .. they consider two points (A and B) a single point(AB) . and make edge between AB to C , instead of plotting two edges between A-B and A-C .. how can i solve this problem  in R